# How to show in-app review dialog when app installed a certain number of days and in use for a certain amount of time?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Google guide about in-app review dialog. i'm using standard Google offers:

```
val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context)

private fun startInnAppReview() {
        val requestFlow = manager.requestReviewFlow()
        requestFlow.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
            if (request.isSuccessful) {
                manager.launchReviewFlow(this, request.result).apply {
                    addOnFailureListener { exception -> Timber.e(exception) }
                }
            } else {
                Timber.e("${request.exception}")
            }
        }
    }
```

And i need to show this in-app dialog only once when app is installed for 5 days and in use more than 20 minutes. Can you explain an optimal variation of making it? I guess we need to use preferences?

Comment: `I guess we need to use preferences?` shared prefs is just storage, you can use files, a local db, whatever you want, isn't relevant here, the bigger problem is how you achieve the rest of your requirements, which is probably too broad to ask here

Answer (score 2):

I would use SharedPreferences and two variables, one for installation time and another one to keep track of the time the app is used, then when both satisfy the conditions, show the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule tasks using WorkManager, you need to check [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to decide which task type(s) best suit your use case.

Comment: WorkManager with Timer class?

Comment: @SoulReaver313 no need for timer, WorkManager handles it for you in the background,  you can specify your work to start after a minimum initial delay for example 
'val myWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>()
   .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.HOURS)
   .build()'